# Can you change your mind after discarding during Monolith Arena?

Tags: etiquette, cheating

In Monolith Arena, [the rules state](https://portalgames.blob.core.windows.net/monolith-arena/Monolith-Arena-Rulebook.pdf):

> after the tiles have been drawn, the player must DISCARD ONE OF THE
> THREE TILES into the discard pile.

This is during the player upkeep step, so the sequence of events:

1. Draw three tiles
2. Discard one tile
3. Consider the remaining tiles and potentially play them

Is it against the rules to retract the discarded tile or change your mind, directly after discarding it, without input from the other player(s)? Asking for a friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know this game at all but will answer this in a broader etiquette sense.

In games people make mistakes or they start taking a move and realise that they want to do something different.  When I play games with people the rule is people can take back things provided it has no effect on anything else or a random event hasn't happened.

So if a player (in any game) is asked to discard a card and then decides they should have discarded another this is fine.  No other player has taken a turn and the only person is disadvantage is the player who exposed a card.

If a player decides to take an action such drawing a card or rolling a dice then this couldn't be taken back after.

When playing games it's about trying to have fun and being reasonable.  Telling a player they can't undo something that has no effect on anything else would be unreasonable.

Comment: Note that *some* games have explicit rules about such things.  E.g. Chess's [Touch-move rule - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch-move_rule#:~:text=The%20touch%2Dmove%20rule%20in,they%20have%20a%20legal%20move.)

Comment: I'm aware of that chess rule.   Put me off the game for many years with memories of being shouted at by other players as a child I have to move that when I've not moved a piece it makes no difference!  I'm not sure what that rule in chess achieves to make a game more friendly or fun tbh.

Comment: My guess about the reason for this rule is that in chess, one could potentially detect the opponent's reaction to the move. Without it, the game of perfect-knowledge logic could degenerate into a game of poker. (But with a child, or even an adult, unless the person *does* start abusing it, I wouldn't invoke the rule.)

Comment: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/16814/what-is-the-idea-behind-the-touch-move-rule. attempts to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is against the rules. The rules (as you quote) do not permit drawing a tile directly after discarding it.

Rather than "is it against the rules?" (a question you seem to already know the answer to), you're asking if it is socially acceptable to break the rules in that fashion. i.e., "are take-backs allowed".

The answer to that is either opinion-based or is (equivalently) "it's up to your group". Even some online implementations of "serious" games like chess allow take-backs (or rather, allow you to request permission from your opponent to do a take-back), even though obviously take-backs are not permitted in chess.